# Getting an image inline with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the testing logo to be inline with my title but it just isn't working and I don't know how to describe the problem so I'll just post a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAM2F.png).
Sample code is below.

```css
.name {
      background-color: #b56663;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Times New Roman";
      color: white;
      height: 100px;
      margin: -8px 0 -5px -20px;
      padding: 20px 0 0 30px; /*Top right bottom left*/
      width: 99.815%;
    }
    
    .name h1 {
        margin: 20px 0 0 150px;
    }
    
    .logo {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin: -53.8px;
        padding: 0 0 0 75px;
        border: 0;
        display: inline;
    }

    body {
        background-color: gray;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
  <div class="name">
    <h1>Lee Shewan</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may restruct your code like this :

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
.name {
  background-color: #b56663;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Times New Roman";
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.name h1 {
  margin:10px 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.name .logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 0 0 75px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <img class="logo" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="logo">
  <h1>Lee Shewan</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: ** By default the H1 tag is styled as a block item i.e it clears it left and right sort of like typing return (enter on your keyboard.) By adding `display:inline-block;` that changes the behavior of the H1 tag. So you can reduce your html code also by placing the img and h1 in the same div tag.

Comment: @omukiguy `By adding display:inline-block; that changes the behavior of the H1 tag` yes i know :) and there is no bad to change the display, like i changed the display of the image :) and yes you can put it inside h1,  make it a background, use position, use flex, grid, etc all valid ways

Comment: Cool, that makes it clearer for Lee and give him more options

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```css
.name {
  background-color: #b56663;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Times New Roman";
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 0 30px 0; /*Top right bottom left*/
}

.name h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 75px;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="name">
     <img class="logo" src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg' alt="logo">
     <h1>Lee Shewan</h1>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!